# How to remove trailing space from the argument in this href-url_encode

Tags: macros

The `\percentifier` in the code below makes sure that we can input e.g. Chinese characters into the first argument of e.g. `\href`, by converting strings into their percent-encoding using `url_encode` *(for further reference, see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395113/67761) to the OP "[How to append a Chinese-character string argument from an environment to first argument of \href](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395101/how-to-append-a-chinese-character-string-argument-from-an-environment-to-first-a)")*.

**`\percentifier`:**

```
\makeatletter
\directlua{function url_encode(str)
  if (str) then
    str = string.gsub (str, "\string\n", "\string\r\string\n")
    str = string.gsub (str, "([^\@percentchar w \@percentchar -\@percentchar _\@percentchar .\@percentchar \string~])",
        function (c) return string.format ("\@percentchar \@percentchar \@percentchar 02X", string.byte(c)) end)
    str = string.gsub (str, " ", "+")
  end
  return str    
end}
\makeatother
%
\def\percentifier#1{\directlua{
tex.print(url_encode('\detokenize{#1}'))
}}
```

**`\href`:**

```
  \href{http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=\percentifier{#1}}{Link}%
```

Another component of our code is the `mainentry`-environment. Let's assume we need such an environment in our answer. In reality, this environment will have multiple arguments, but of course I minimized/simplified it for the purpose of a **MWE**. Its first argument will always be used to complete an URL:

**`mainentry`-environment:**

```
\newenvironment {mainentry}
  {\mainentryA}
%
  {\clearpage}
%
\def\mainentryA#1{%
     #1 \href{http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=\percentifier{#1}}{Link}%
    }{
 }
```

In the **MWE** below, notice that the code works perfect for `Test1` (since it is presented as `Test1%`. However, the code does not work well for `Test2` (because Tex interprets a trailing space after it, which due to the `url_encode` adds a `+`).

Now, my intend is not to change the behavior of changing a space into a `+`, which should be done to have a properly functioning `url_encode`. Nevertheless, I do not want Tex to interpret the instance of `Test2` as having a trailing space. So, perhaps the solution could be solved in the definition of `\percentifier`, or if not: in the definition of `\mainentryA`.

Please note I do NOT want to use Solution 1 or Solution 2 from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395098/67761) to another OP entitled "[Why is this code outputting clickable URLs for some users, yet not for others?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395097/why-is-this-code-outputting-clickable-urls-for-some-users-yet-not-for-others)".

I would rather have a solution similar to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395268/67761). Something using `\cs_set_eq:NN\Trim\tl_trim_spaces:n` or a similar construct. Somehow, I have not been able to do so.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%%%%%%%
% \percentifier
\makeatletter
\directlua{function url_encode(str)
  if (str) then
    str = string.gsub (str, "\string\n", "\string\r\string\n")
    str = string.gsub (str, "([^\@percentchar w \@percentchar -\@percentchar _\@percentchar .\@percentchar \string~])",
        function (c) return string.format ("\@percentchar \@percentchar \@percentchar 02X", string.byte(c)) end)
    str = string.gsub (str, " ", "+")
  end
  return str    
end}
\makeatother
%
\def\percentifier#1{\directlua{
tex.print(url_encode('\detokenize{#1}'))
}}
%
%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%
% \mainentry
\newenvironment {mainentry}
  {\mainentryA}
%
  {\clearpage}
%
\def\mainentryA#1{%
     #1 \href{http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=\percentifier{#1}}{Link}%
    }{
 }
%
%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{mainentry}{%
Test1%
}
\end{mainentry}

\begin{mainentry}{%
Test2
}
\end{mainentry}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can probably do that with Lua, and with expl3, plus you always have an option to do `\def\removespacethenpercentify#1 \relax{\percentifier{#1}}` and use `\href{...\removespacethenpercentify#1\relax}{Link}`.

Comment: @Manuel Do you have a working MWE for that last option please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stripping trailing space from an argument you can use the `\stripspace` macro defined by following two lines:

```
\def\stripspace#1#2{\stripspaceA#2\end/ \end/\relax#1{#2}}
\def\stripspaceA#1 \end/#2\relax#3#4{\if\relax#2\relax#3{#4}\else#3{#1}\fi}

\def\percentifier#1{[#1]} % just for testing

\stripspace\percentifier {text1 and text}
\stripspace\percentifier {text2 and text }
without stripping: \percentifier{text3 and text }

\bye
```

This is full expandable solution.

In your application you can replace

```
\href{http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=\percentifier{#1}}{Link}%
```

by

```
\href{http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=\stripspace\percentifier{#1}}{Link}%
```